# How to draw IRFs and confidence bands in R

Tags: r, time-series, confidence-interval, vector-autoregression, impulse-response

How can I plot Impulse Responses Functions and confidence bands in R as shown in the image below:

I [image]

Comment: See the [`vars` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vars/index.html).

Comment: Thanks @Christoph, but I want to have some sort of shading between the confidence bands as in this image.

Comment: If you retrieve the upper and lower values of the bands, you can do that with the general purpose `polygon` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer using the `polygon` function in `R`

```
#Generate some psuedo data
x = seq(0,10,.01)
IRF = sin(pi*x/5)+.8*cos(4*pi*x/5)  #This is the IRF values
lower = IRF - 1                     #Lower 95% limit
upper = IRF + 1                     #Upper 95% limit

plot(x,IRF,type="n",ylim=c(-3,3))
polygon(c(x,rev(x)),c(lower,rev(upper)),col="lightgrey",border=NA)  #This function creates the CI bands
lines(x,IRF,col="darkblue")
box()
```

This code generates the following image:

[image]

Comment: My code makes the assumptions that you can calculate or have the values for IRF and the upper and lower limits of the confidence interval.